# Parse only date from array list in android

Tags: java, android, date, arraylist

I am using a `CalendarPickerview` in m android app which helps me in selecting multiple dates. I am getting the selected dates in an `arraylist<>`.The problem is that I am getting the date in the format `[Sun Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015]`.
But I should get the date in the format 04/10/2015.How can I achieve the same.
Thanks in advance.
Below given is the sample code I used.

```
 calendar=(CalendarPickerView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.calendar_view);
    Date today=new Date();
    calendar.init(today,nextYear.getTime()).withSelectedDate(today).inMode(CalendarPickerView.SelectionMode.MULTIPLE );
   // calendar.highlightDates(getHolidays());
    String[] items1 = new String[]{"Select Something"};
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, items1);
    button= (Button) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.action_next);
    datesSelected = (TextView) rootView2.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Date>selectedDates=(ArrayList<Date>)calendar
                    .getSelectedDates();
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), selectedDates.toString(),
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
            String dates=selectedDates.toString();
            datesSelected.setText(dates);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use SimpleDateFormat to convert date in desired format, like:

```
public static String getFormatedDate(String strDate, String sourceFormate,
        String destinyFormate) {
    SimpleDateFormat df;
    df = new SimpleDateFormat(sourceFormate);
    Date date = null;
    try {
        date = df.parse(strDate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    df = new SimpleDateFormat(destinyFormate);
    return df.format(date);

}
```

Where, `strDate` is the date, `sourceFormate` is current date format and `destinyFormate` is the desired date format.

Call getFormatedDate like:

```
getFormatedDate(strDate,
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            "mm/dd/yyyy");
```

Hope, it helps you.

Comment: Thank you for your help Rahul . But I am getting null pointer exception at getFormatedDate(strDate,
            "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
            "mm/dd/yyyy"); and at   return df.format(date); .

Comment: You getting null pointer because "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" is not your date format, this is just for example. Use format of date you sending in "strDate". Date format for "[Sun Oct 04 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2015]" is "[EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy]". try this

Comment: I have tried the same.But now also I am getting the same nullpointer exception @ function calling point and return.

Comment: Please provide full exception from stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you get a list of `Date` objects here.

```
ArrayList<Date>selectedDates=(ArrayList<Date>)calendar.getSelectedDates();
```

The format you mention is just what `Log` or `println()` show (using `Date.toString()` to convert the Date to a String).

You can use `SimpleDateFormat` etc. to convert the `Date` objects to any format you want.